# Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory when systemctl is run from docker as a non-root user

Tags: systemd, docker, systemd-journald, container, docker-compose

I am trying to run a centos+python3 based docker container as a non-root user and then trying to get the systemctl status of a host service from the container.

```
docker run --user=3001:3001 --userns=host -ti -v /run/systemd:/run/systemd --pid=host centos-python:latest /bin/bash
```

I am getting the error `Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory` when i run `systemctl status httpd.service`

Whereas when I run as a root user I get the systemctl status of the service which is running in host correctly.

Is there any additional volume mounts that needs to be done for running as a non-root user or is it not possible to get the systemctl status as a non-root user